# Code to check particular element is the last child in XML Parser

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml-parsing

I have below structure in XML code and

```
<drinks>
<soft>
<subject>
<soft>
<subject>
<brand-name></brand-name>
<subject>
<brand-name></brand-name>
</subject>
</subject>
<link></link>    
<soft>
<nature>
<brand-name></brand-name>
<link></link>
</nature>
<info></info>
</drinks>
```

i need to confirm `<info>` is the last child of `<drinks>` i dont have any idea to do this... I try below

```
var $element = $xml.find("drinks").addBack("drinks");
alert($element.children().last().nodeName);
```

I also need to confirm for every `<subject>` `<brand-name>` is the first child. I try below code

```
function check_first_child(parent, child, rule, error_type)
{
    if(($xml.find(parent).length > 0))
    {
        var $parent = $xml.find(parent).addBack(parent);
        $parent.children().first().each(function()
        {
            alert(this.nodeName);
        });
    }
}
```

But the above code find subject only one time . totally i have two subject.

Comment: @trincot can you guide me

Answer (score 0):

```
var $element = $xml.find("drinks").addBack("drinks");
var lastelement = $element.children().last().get(0).nodeName;
```